# Page Change - Error Message : Something Went Wrong

Tags: wordpress, caching, error-handling, wordpress-theming

I transferred my client's website from the Wordpress server to Hostinger. Since then, on a particular page on mobile and destok an error message constantly reappears when you click on next.

The only way to resolve the problem is to clear the cache manually on the Hostinger interface.

The website was created from a template.

Website page : https://mangaautoimport.com/inventory/
Website template: https://themeforest.net/item/car-dealer-automotive-responsive-wordpress-theme/20213334

[error message on destok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k6G6.jpg)

I tried to disable several plugging and Hostinger tools as well as find the error in the source code.
I contacted Hostinger and the problem does not seem to be with their server or their end.

Comment: For what it's worth:  I cannot get this error to happen on my computer no matter how many times I click Next.  Have you tried opening the site in a browser you have never used to visit the site to see if the error occurs there?